# No accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: vb.net, lucene.net

```
Sub CreatePersonsIndex(ByVal dt As System.Data.DataTable)
        Try
            'Specify the index file location where the indexes are to be stored
            Dim indexFileLocation As String = "C:\Users\Shahrukh\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WpfApplication33\WpfApplication33\App_Data"
            Dim dir As Lucene.Net.Store.Directory = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexFileLocation, True)
            Dim indexWriter As New IndexWriter(dir, New StandardAnalyzer(), True)
            indexWriter.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(10.0)
            indexWriter.SetUseCompoundFile(False)
            indexWriter.SetMaxMergeDocs(10000)
            indexWriter.SetMergeFactor(100)

            If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
                        'Create the Document object
                        Dim doc As New Document()
                        For Each dc As System.Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns
                            'Populate the document with the column name and value from our query
                            doc.Add(New Field(dc.ColumnName, dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED))
                        Next
                        ' Write the Document to the catalog
                        indexWriter.AddDocument(doc)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            ' Close the writer
            indexWriter.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

using this code got an **error**

> " No accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments."

help me to solve this

Comment: Post the entire error. There are several instances where you are using "New" in the above code. Bottom line, on one of those lines, you've provided the wrong number of arguments when creating an object.

Comment: Dim indexWriter As New IndexWriter(dir, New StandardAnalyzer(), True) in this line of code i got an error " No accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: You're providing 3 arguments. How many does the class say it should accept? Post the code for the IndexWriter class (just the constructors)

Comment: i did not got your  what are u trying to say?

Comment: i am posting all the code

Comment: Do you have the code for the IndexWriter class?

Comment: Which version of the Lucene classes are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use to you: [Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx)